# Major discrepancy between Cassandra coordinator latency and client latency

Tags: performance, cassandra

When I measure our p99 read latency at the coordinator with cassandra.ClientRequest.ReadLatency.p99, I get a time of ~20ms. When I        measure it from our client applications using the DataStax Java driver, I get a p99 of ~100ms. The raw round trip time (network overhead) between these machines is ~6ms. Is the remaining discrepancy typical? Or is there some problem to solve here? The only other likely culprit I can think of is garbage collection on the coordinator node.

Answer (score 0):

Delays in network + kernel + driver deserialization + gcs is most likely cause with coordinated omission making them not tracked well. Also how you are measuring them is important, but the drivers metric is what is most likely metric that is interesting to you since thats the time your application sees. Most time outside the ClientRequest metric are things you have to resolve with environment. Although you might wanna make sure you dont have things in blocked state in the NativeTransport stage (tpstats) which will be held up before the request "start time" is marked.

Id recommend trying to use [hdr histogram](https://bitbucket.org/marshallpierce/hdrhistogram-metrics-reservoir) for monitoring as well, since if your using the Metrics timer its use of a sampling reservoir (what driver using by default) is very bad at tracking long tail latencies accurately.